# Decidability of Interpreted Theory

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

If a theory $T'$ is interpretable in a theory $T$ and $T$ is decidable, is it true that $T'$ must be decidable as well?

Comment: @HanulJeon Technically one needs to care that the translation of formulas corresponding to the interpretation is computable. It is always the case  if the signature of interpreted theory is finite. But for infinite signatures one could have non-computable interpretation of an undecidable theory in a decidable one.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov I was not careful; I did not notice there are such an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, the theory $T'$ of groups is known to be undecidable, but it is clearly interpretable in the theory $T$ of torsion-free divisible abelian groups $(\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces), which is decidable.

On the other hand, if $T'$ a *complete* theory which is interpretable in $T$, via a *computable* interpretation, and $T$ is decidable, then $T'$ is decidable.

And if $T'$ and $T$ are *bi-interpretable*, via *computable* interpretations, and $T$ is decidable, then $T'$ is decidable.

Computable here means that the function assigning to each symbol of the language $L'$ of $T'$ its corresponding formula in the language $L$ of $T$ must be computable. It follows that the map $\varphi\mapsto \hat{\varphi}$ from $L'$-formulas to corresponding $L$-formulas is computable.

So given an $L'$-sentence $\varphi$, we know that if $T'\vdash \varphi$, then $T\vdash \hat{\varphi}$. If we knew the converse, that if $T\vdash \hat{\varphi}$, then $T'\vdash \varphi$, then we could computably reduce the question of whether $T\vdash \varphi$ to the question of whether $T\vdash \hat{\varphi}$.

If $T'$ is complete, then if $T'\not\vdash \varphi$, then $T'\vdash \lnot \varphi$, so $T\vdash \lnot \varphi$, and $T\not \vdash \varphi$. So we have the desired converse. If $T'$ is not complete, but $T'$ and $T$ are bi-interpretable, we can also get the converse: If $T\vdash \hat{\varphi}$, then $T'\vdash \hat{\hat{\varphi}}$, which implies $T\vdash \varphi$ (using the definition of bi-interpretation).